# How to access the sender object or button form a jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery sortable list in which you can drop (clone) items from a draggable list. I want the user to be able to change some text on a dropped element. So I display the value and I hold a copy in a hidden input field.

On click of any of the elements, a jquery dialog opens and the text is set in a text input in the dialog. On close, the new value is set back again on the element text and the hidden input.

How can the dialog know which element requested the text change?

Right now I'm using a global var to hold that information. But I think it's ugly. There must be some way to give the sender to the dialog.open?

```
// Global for holding the dialog sender
var dialogSender = null;

// Edit element
$('.element').live('click', function() {
    dialogSender = $(this);
    // prev() is the hidden input
    $('#dialog-form input[name=content]').val($(this).prev().val());
    $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
});

// Dialog for editing elements
$('#dialog-form').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Ok': function() {
            val = $('#dialog-form input[name=content]').val();
            // Set the text back to the element and the hidden input
            dialogSender.text(val).prev().val(val);
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to associate the button that was clicked with your dialog widget, then read back that information in your `Ok` button handler:

```
$(".element").live("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // prev() is the hidden input
    $("#dialog-form input[name=content]").val($this.prev().val());
    $("#dialog-form").data("dialogSender", $this).dialog('open');
});
```

---

```
'Ok': function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $("#dialog-form input[name=content]").val();
    // Set the text back to the element and the hidden input.
    $this.data("dialogSender").text(val).prev().val(val);
    $this.dialog("close");
},
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! B.t.w I changed `live()` (http://api.jquery.com/live/) to `on()` (http://api.jquery.com/on/) as the former is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current sender button by adding a event argument, for an example:

```
// Dialog for editing elements
$('#dialog-form').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Ok': function(evt) {
            val = $('#dialog-form input[name=content]').val();
            // Set the text back to the element and the hidden input
            dialogSender.text(val).prev().val(val);
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Cancel: function(evt) {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

And the button you pressed will be in evt.currentTarget. You can check it out by add this line to your 'OK' function:

```
console.debug(evt.currentTarget);
```

Comment: I don't want to know what dialog button was pressed. There is only one OK button anyway. I want to know which element triggered the dialog to open.

Comment: it is the same, added the argument 'evt' in the listener function for .live(), and find the currentTarget.

Comment: `$('.element').live('click', function(evt){console.debug(evt.currentTarget);})`